# CSS trick to manage border colors

Tags: jquery, html, css

What I'm trying to do should be simple but I don't know of any tricks or methods to accomplish it.

I have an element on my page. A 100x100 div with a class of 'fooditem'
When you hover, it gets a blue border
When you click, it gets a permanent green border

The issue is :hover and the base clases are competing. I want :hover to only apply to elements without the .fooditem-selected class.

Here's a fiddle to play with it. It works pretty much how I want, but I know I'm using conflicting css rules: http://jsfiddle.net/96BHd/2/

Is there a simple fix or trick that I am overlooking?

**CSS**

```
.fooditem {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
}

.fooditem:hover {
    transition: .5s;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #4F91FF;
}

.fooditem-selected {
    transition: .5s;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #6dff70;
}

.fooditem-selected:hover {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 6px #6dff70;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".fooditem").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("fooditem-selected")){
        $(this).removeClass("fooditem-selected");
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("fooditem-selected");
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: I had to add .fooditem-selected:hover because the base class (.fooditem:hover) was still applying the blue border after the item was selected. That is the 'hack' I am looking to fix

Comment: Your fiddle works fine for me in Chrome, green border stays green http://jsfiddle.net/96BHd/2/

Comment: I am not seeing any problem in Firefox. The only thing I saw that might be a problem is if you intended selected items to have a different hover color... the css has it use the same border color in the hover class that it already has from the -selected on. http://jsfiddle.net/96BHd/3/ -- using a different color for -selected hover.

Comment: @Andrew - It works how I want but I know it's hacked. I was wondering if there is a better way to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/96BHd/7/

Simplified CSS and Javascript. Uses :not() to prevent superfluous classes. You really don't need vendor prefixes on box-shadow (http://css-tricks.com/do-we-need-box-shadow-prefixes/).

JS

```
$(".fooditem").click(function () {
 $(this).toggleClass("selected");
});
```

CSS

```
.fooditem{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    float:left;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: .5s;
}
.fooditem:not(.selected):hover {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #4F91FF;
}
.fooditem.selected {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #6dff70;
}
```

Comment: This is a indeed better way , +1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser support you're looking for, you can use the `:not()` pseudo selector. It's a CSS3 selector, so caniuse.com says it should work on IE9+ and all non-IE browsers. If you need more support, you might get it with a selector shim.

To use it:

```
.fooditem:not(.fooditem-selected):hover
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing particularly *wrong* with the way you have it and I wouldn't even consider it a hack, as you're using basic CSS.  However I am a fan of having negative states.

```
.fooditem{
}

.fooditem-notselected {
}

.fooditem-notselected:hover {
}

.fooditem-selected {
}
```

And using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```
$(".fooditem").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("fooditem-notselected")
    .toggleClass("fooditem-selected");

  // or .toggleClass("fooditem-notselected fooditem-selected");
});
```

These styles are a bit more descriptive so it should be easier to understand, especially for someone who is looking at your code for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a nonActive class to the div, and change `fooditem:hover` to `fooditem-nonActive:hover`, than in the js , remove the `fooditem-nonActive` class , add the `fooditem-selected` class :

Add a nonActive class to the div:

```
<div class='fooditem nonActive'></div>
```

change the hover in css :

```
.nonActive:hover {
    // style stays the same
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: .5s;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #4f91ff;
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #4F91FF;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 6px #4F91FF;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".fooditem").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("fooditem-selected")) {
        $(this).removeClass("fooditem-selected");
        $(this).addClass("nonActive");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("nonActive");
        $(this).addClass("fooditem-selected");
    }
});
```

**A working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/96BHd/5/

btw I love those boxes, they are so cute :D

Comment: Instead of using a "nonActive" state, cluttering the divs with a bunch of classes, why don't you use the psuedo CSS selector :not()? It works in all modern(ish) browsers. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/